# Good website for an introduction to MathML?

Tags: xml, mathml

I cannot find a reasonable video or website which explains and teaches MathML in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MathML Fundamental

http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML3/chapter2.html

MathMl introduction

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML

MathML with html5

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_mathml.htm

MathML browser test

https://eyeasme.com/Joe/MathML/MathML_browser_test

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing heavily using HTML5 and relying on chrome. Chrome doesn't support MATHML yet although the underlying rendering engine-webkit build seems to have MATHML support enabled by default.

Comment: Well, that's Chrome's problem, then. ;) Depending on the scenario (on my blog, yes; on a client's site, no), I'm all for using a standard technology that will break certain browsers.